# WorkflowScript.with in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a class in a jenkins shared library that stores the instance of a WorkflowScript class from a jenkins pipeline script as shown below.

`def myTools = new my.org.MyTools(this)`

the constructore of MyTools just stores the instance of WorkflowScript like this...

```
MyTools(script){
    this.script = script
}
```

then I have a method that tries to use groovy's `.with` on `script` but fails...

```
myMethod(){
    script.with{
        node{
            echo "I want to be able to use pipeline syntax here"
            sh 'echo "without using script. in front of each command"'
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run this i get the following error...

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2.node() is applicable for argument types: (org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2) values: [org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@855f14e]
Possible solutions: clone(), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), notify(), wait(), call(), run()
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:58)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite
.java:113)
```

I would have expected the inside of the `script.with` closure to have access to all of the same stuff as `script.`, but it looks like it only has access to methods of `java.lang.Object`. Is it possible to get the `script.with` closure to function with the same context of `script.`?

Comment: Did you check the security section in Jenkins to see if it blocked access to "secure" function? I remember getting similar errors when running scripts in the beginning. You may need to go through and click "accept" in the dashboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for groovy closure possible to specify [strategy which the closure uses to resolve methods and properties](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Closure.html#setResolveStrategy-int-)

there are options: DELEGATE_FIRST, DELEGATE_ONLY, OWNER_FIRST (default), OWNER_ONLY, TO_SELF

i think the pipeline script has a special strategy, and in your class there is a default one.

Comment: your answer definitely lead me in the right direction. I ended up creating a closure with the pipeline script inside of it, then setting the delegate of that closure to the instance of the jenkins pipeline WorkflowScript that I'm working with. `pipelineClosure.setDelegate(jenkinsWorkflowScript)`

Comment: @MicahPotter do you mind adding your solution to the question or add a new answer? That would really useful!

Comment: @Makers_F I posted a solution. Better later than never!

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyTools {
    def script

    def myMethod(){
        def closure = {
            echo "I want to be able to use pipeline syntax here!"
        }
        closure.setDelegate(this.script)
        closure()
    }
}

stage('XXX') {
    steps {
        script {
            def myTools = new MyTools(script:this)
            myTools.myMethod()
        }
    }
}
```