# WorkflowScript Jenkins Pipeline Source Code

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have been trying to locate the source code of the WorkflowScript class that is referenced to by `this` in the Jenkins Pipeline script but can't seem to find it. Basically I just want to find out what methods are found in the class other than the ones that I have discovered online like `.with` so that I can use them in the pipeline script or shared library. Can someone please point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: [This is the base scripting class that the scripts are compiled into at the time of this writing](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/CpsScript.java)

Comment: So how do I know what methods are exposed by this base scripting class?

Comment: I don't think I understand what you are asking - most of it is accomplished through use of the dynamic parts of Groovy with `invokeMethod` and `getProperty`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was actually referring to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44569712/workflowscript-with-in-jenkins on where the `.with` came from but I understood that that's actually groovy syntax